# Devise + Omniauth + Heroku undefined method in #new_with_session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, devise, omniauth

Social login is working great in development, but once pushed to heroku I am getting `` NoMethodError (undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass) `` in `new`.

From my user model:

```
def self.new_with_session(params, session)
  if session["devise.user_attributes"]
    new(session["devise.user_attributes"], without_protection: true) do |user|
      user.attributes = params
      user.valid?
    end
  else
    super
  end
end
```

I've reached a roadblock in my debugging. Any thoughts? Debugging ideas? Similar experiences?

Comment: You have some variable as nil when it was not supposed to. Where is that each call? But most likely you forgot to config your production environment ;)

Answer (score 0):

Solved! The problem was actually with the acts_as_taggable_on gem. Since `session["devise.user_attributes"]` included all of the `User` attributes, when it got to one of them that "acts_as_taggable", like in my case "skills" or "interests", it appears the gems magic turns that into a multiparameter or nested paramater attribute and so then rails tries to loop over the values - which is nil in my case. So, if `"skills"=>nil` is present, I get an `undefined method each for nil` error.

I haven't checked out the gems source in too much depth yet to confirm where the issue is there, but I believe the error in rails is coming from line 25 or 27 in https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb.

Simple solution was to add `session["devise.user_attributes"].delete_if { |k,v| v.blank? }` to my `new_with_session` method.

```
def self.new_with_session(params, session)
  if session["devise.user_attributes"]
    session = session["devise.user_attributes"].delete_if { |k,v| v.blank? }
    new(session, without_protection: true) do |user|
      user.attributes = params
      user.valid?
    end
  else
    super
  end
end
```